# Restart WPF Application from non-UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

In my WPF app I need to run a quick routine on startup that checks for a new available version. If the version is available, we do the update and then would like to immediately restart the app. Since this is run before the main window appears to the user, it simply appears as though the app took a split second longer to start up.

We're using [Squirrel.Windows](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/tree/master/docs) for our updater. I've made the class below to handle checking for/applying updates.

```
public class UpdateVersion
{
    private readonly UpdateManager _updateManager;

    public Action<int> Progress;
    public event Action Restart;
    public UpdateVersion(string squirrelUrl)
    {
        _updateManager = new UpdateManager(squirrelUrl);
    }

    public async Task UpdateVersions()
    {
        using (_updateManager)
        {
            UpdateInfo updateInfo = await _updateManager.CheckForUpdate(progress:Progress);
            if (updateInfo.CurrentlyInstalledVersion == null)
            {
                if (updateInfo.FutureReleaseEntry != null)
                {
                    await _updateManager.UpdateApp(Progress);

                    // Job crashes here
                    Restart?.Invoke();
                }
            }
            else if (updateInfo.CurrentlyInstalledVersion.Version < updateInfo.FutureReleaseEntry.Version)
            {
                await _updateManager.UpdateApp(Progress);

                // Job crashes here
                Restart?.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately Squirrel has made their update process `async` only, which means the `CheckForUpdate` and `UpdateApp` method must use `await`, making the entire update method asynchronous. I assign the asnyc call to a `Task`, then simply `.Wait()` for the update to finish.

The problem comes when I try to restart my app. Based on what I've read, I need to use `Dispatcher.Invoke` to call the restart due to the fact I am on a non-UI thread when performing the update. However, despite the code below, I still get the same error message:

> The Calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Any idea how to correctly implement `Dispatcher.Invoke` in order to restart the app?

```
        // Instantiate new UpdateVersion object passing in the URL
        UpdateVersion updateVersion = new UpdateVersion(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SquirrelDirectory"));

        // Assign Dispatch.Invoke as Restart action delegate
        updateVersion.Restart += () =>
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                Process.Start(ResourceAssembly.Location);
                Current.Shutdown();
            });
        };

        // This is here for debugging purposes so I know the update is occurring
        updateVersion.Progress += (count) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Progress.. {count}");
        };

        var task = Task.Run(async () => { await updateVersion.UpdateVersions(); });
        task.Wait();
```

**EDIT**

Below is a screen shot of the `Target` attribute of the `Restart` action. The debugger was paused at the `Restar?.Invoke` line from above.

[image]

Comment: Where is the code running, is it in your Program.cs or an `Application` event?

Comment: No Program.cs file it's the `OnStartup` method of the application. This is the first command the program runs.

Comment: You might consider adding a `Program.cs` with a `Main` method (like a console app), set that as your startup object (under Properties -> Application) and then do your updating from there.  That way you can simply choose not to launch your main window when there is an update to be done.

Comment: Unfortunately not an option to alter the startup process at this point.

Comment: Based on the code you show here and your comment saying the code is executed in the `OnStartup()` method, I would expect the program to deadlock, rather than throw an exception. And indeed, when I try to reproduce the issue, that's exactly what happens (i.e. deadlock). Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. Note that while you are using a third-party library, there doesn't seem to be anything about the question itself specific to that; you should be able to reproduce the problem simply by simulating that library's actions.

Comment: `async` is *not* a problem. The problem was created by the attempts to "fix" a non-existent issue. *Why* do you call `.Wait()` instead of simply calling `await` ? Why use a `Restart` event instead of simply awaiting `UpdateVersions()` ? Why `var task = Task.Run(async () => { await updateVersion.UpdateVersions(); });task.Wait();` instead of just `await updateVersion.UpdateVersions();` ?

Comment: Also why a Progress event instead of the `Progress<T>` class? All this code is actually trying to convert Tasks into the older event-based pattern. It's a *lot* simpler to write clean async code and ther is absolutely no reason to use Invoke. After `await` you are back in the UI thread so you could simply restart from it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to convert asynchronous programming to the old event based pattern, just use it properly. You don't need events to detect when an asynchronous operation finished, nor do you need `Invoke` to move back to the UI thread. `await` takes care of both.

You could write code as simple as this:

```
static readonly SemanticVersion ZeroVersion = new SemanticVersion(0, 0, 0, 0);


private async void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    await CheckForUpdatesAsync();
}

private async Task CheckForUpdatesAsync()
{
    string squirrelUrl = "...";


    var updateProgress = new Progress<int>();
    IProgress<int> progress = updateProgress;

    //Create a splash screen that binds to progress and show it
    var splash = new UpdateSplash(updateProgress);
    splash.Show();

    using (var updateManager = new UpdateManager(squirrelUrl))
    {

        //IProgress<int>.Report matches Action<i>
        var info = await updateManager.CheckForUpdate(progress: progress.Report);

        //Get the current and future versions. 
        //If missing, replace them with version Zero
        var currentVersion = info.CurrentlyInstalledVersion?.Version ?? ZeroVersion;
        var futureVersion = info.FutureReleaseEntry?.Version ?? ZeroVersion;

        //Is there a newer version?
        if (currentVersion < futureVersion)
        {
            await updateManager.UpdateApp(progress.Report);
            Restart();
        }
    }
    splash.Hide();
}

private void Restart()
{
    Process.Start(ResourceAssembly.Location);
    Current.Shutdown();
}
```

This is just enough code to extract to a separate class:

```
private async void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
        var updater = new Updater();
        await updater.CheckForUpdatesAsync(...);
}

// ...

class Updater
{
    static readonly SemanticVersion ZeroVersion = new SemanticVersion(0, 0, 0, 0);


    public async Task CheckForUpdatesAsync(string squirrelUrl)
    {
        var updateProgress = new Progress<int>();
        IProgress<int> progress = updateProgress;

        //Create a splash screen that binds to progress and show it
        var splash = new UpdateSplash(updateProgress);
        splash.Show();

        using (var updateManager = new UpdateManager(squirrelUrl))
        {

            var updateInfo = await updateManager.CheckForUpdate(progress: progress.Report);

            //Get the current and future versions. If missing, replace them with version Zero
            var currentVersion = updateInfo.CurrentlyInstalledVersion?.Version ?? ZeroVersion;
            var futureVersion = updateInfo.FutureReleaseEntry?.Version ?? ZeroVersion;

            //Is there a newer version?
            if (currentVersion < futureVersion)
            {
                await updateManager.UpdateApp(progress.Report);
                Restart();
            }
        }
        splash.Hide();
    }

    private void Restart()
    {
        Process.Start(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location);
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the actual exception is somewhere in the `Restart` handler is trying to access the `MainWindow` get property from another thread based on the stack trace. This is a complete guess, but I would store the original `Dispatcher` in the `OnStartup` method and use the stored Dispatcher in the `Restart` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using `SplashScreen` ? This `SplashScreen` would check for new versions, and either download updates, or start the old application.

A lovely tutorial to get you started : [EASILY CREATE A WPF SPLASH SCREEN WITH STATUS UPDATES VIA MVVM](http://jkshay.com/easily-create-wpf-splash-screen-status-updates-via-mvvm/)